# On an isomorphism between quotient spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and let $N$ be a closed subspace of $Y$.

Suppose that the map $T:X \longrightarrow Y$ is an isometric isomorphism and suppose that the restriction map  $T|_M:M \longrightarrow N$ also is an isometric isomorphism.

Is it true that the quotient spaces $X/M$ and $Y/N$ are isometrically isomorphic, too? My intuition says that the answer is affirmative. In this case, what would be the relevant isometry between $X/M$ and $Y/N$?

Comment: Did you want $T$ to be linear?  Also, your result seems difficult if $\dim Y$ is greater than $\dim X$.  For instance:  $Y = \Bbb{R}^3$, $X$ is the $xy$-plane, $M$ and $N$ are the $x$-axis and $T$ is the inclusion map (projection onto first two coordinates).  Then $X/M$ and $Y/M$ are one and two dimensional, respectively, so somewhat tricky to be isomorphic.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are isomorphic then they have the same dimension.

Comment: @Eric Towers: Yes, $T$ is linear.

Comment: @copper.hat : D'oh.  Clearly too late (here) for MSE.

Comment: @EricTowers: Have a glass of wine :-), but if you drink, don't derive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y \in Y$, then $\|[y]]| = \inf_{n \in N} \|y+n\|$. Since $y = Tx$ for some $x\in X$ and $n = Tm$ for some $m \in M$, we see that
$\|[y]]| = \inf_{m \in M} \|Tx + Tm\| = \inf_{m \in M} \|T(x+m)\| = \inf_{m \in M} \|x+m\| = \|[x]\|$.

In particular, the map $[T][x] = [Tx]$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @serenus: Glad to be able to help.